# Why can't I use __getattr__ with Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, getattr

I've seen examples online of people using `__getattr__` with Django models, but whenever I try I get errors. (Django 1.2.3)

I don't have any problems when I am using `__getattr__` on normal objects.  For example:

```
class Post(object):
     def __getattr__(self, name):
         return 42
```

Works just fine...

> ```
>  >>> from blog.models import Post
>  >>> p = Post()
>  >>> p.random
>  42
> ```

Now when I try it with a Django model:

```
from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
     def __getattr__(self, name):
         return 42
```

And test it on on the interpreter:

> ```
>  >>> from blog.models import Post
>  >>> p = Post()
>  ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input The
> ```
>
> following traceback may be corrupted
>   or invalid The error message is: ('EOF
>   in multi-line statement', (6, 0))
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> /Users/josh/project/
>   in ()
>
> /Users/josh/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc
>   in **init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       338             if kwargs:
>       339                 raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword
>   argument for this function" %
>   kwargs.keys()[0])
>   --> 340         signals.post_init.send(sender=self.**class**,
>   instance=self)
>       341 
>       342     def **repr**(self):
>
> /Users/josh/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.pyc
>   in send(self, sender, **named)
>       160 
>       161         for receiver in self._live_receivers(_make_id(sender)):
>   --> 162             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender,
>   **named)
>       163             responses.append((receiver, response))
>       164         return responses
>
> /Users/josh/project/python2.6/site-packages/photologue/models.pyc
>   in add_methods(sender, instance,
>   signal, *args, **kwargs)
>       728     """
>       729     if hasattr(instance, 'add_accessor_methods'):
>   --> 730         instance.add_accessor_methods()
>       731 
>       732 # connect the add_accessor_methods function to the
>   post_init signal
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not
>   callable

Can someone explain what is going on?

---

EDIT: I may have been too abstract in the examples, here is some code that is closer to what I actually would use on the website:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField()
    content = RichTextField('Content', blank=True, null=True)
    # Etc...

Class CuratedPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ''' If the user tries to access a property of the CuratedPost, return the property of the Post instead...  '''
        return self.post.name

    # Etc...
```

While I *could* create a property for each attribute of the Post class, that would lead to a lot of code duplication.  Further more, that would mean anytime I add or edit a attribute of the Post class I would have to remember to make the same change to the CuratedPost class, which seems like a recipe for code rot.

Comment: is that really "return self.post.name"? It should be "return getattr(self.post, name)"

Comment: Indeed, that is what the code should be

Comment: I've run into infinite recursion problems using a similar pattern in the case that the `name` input is itself `"post"`.

Answer (score 7):

One must be careful using __getattr__ . Only intercept what you know, and let the base class handle what you do not.

The first step is, can you use a property instead? If you want a "random" attribute which return 42 then this is much safer:

```
class Post(...):
  @property
  def random(self):
    return 42
```

If you want "random_*" (like "random_1", "random_34", etc) to do something then you'll have to use __getattr__ like this:

```
class Post(...):
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name.startswith("random_"):
      return name[7:]
    return super(Post, self).__getattr__(name)
```

Comment: The example I used in my post was supposed to show that even very simple applications of the __getattr__ property break when I extend the Django model object.  I have updated my original post to include something closer to what I would actually use.

Comment: I don't believe this will work with Django, because models.Model has no `__getattr__`, so your `super(Post, self).__getattr__(...)` should throw an exception.

Comment: Have you tried it? Python provides a default __getattr__, so it 'should' not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Django sends certain signals when models are first initialized (ie, by loading up the shell) - by making it so that calls to `__getattr` always return an integer, you've modified the code in a way that Django signals weren't expecting (and therefore, they're breaking).

If you want to do this, maybe try it this way:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
  if hasattr(self, attr):
    return super(MyModel, self).__getattr__(attr)
  return 42
```

Comment: This doesn't work since hasattr(self, attr) ends up calling \_\_getattr\_\_ recursively. You want "attr in self.__dict__" instead.

Comment: And actually, that won't work either since \_\_getattr\_\_ is only called if attr is not in \_\_dict\_\_

Comment: @Andrew: Sounds like you could do that with `__getattribute__`, though

Comment: @Cameron: \_\_getattribute\_\_ is also tricky, just in different ways. I suspect @Joshmaker should use a property instead.

Comment: The "Return 42" is just an example, `__getattr__` breaks no matter what I have it return.  I've seen code samples from older Django projects that used `__getattr__` without problem and I can't find any documentation that says it has been deprecated.