# Issue with __getattr__ when upgrading from python 2.7 to python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to upgrade my Django 1.10 project from python 2.7 to python 3, and basically have issues with the following code snippet:

```
class QuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        return self.get_queryset()
```

If I comment out `__getattr__` part from my code, everything works just fine. Otherwise, I end up with error:

`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`

Any ideas how to rewrite the code to run under python 3.x ?

Comment: A quick google of "`django python 3 __getattr__`" led to the possibility that maybe you need to intercept just the attributes you're expecting and pass the rest on to the parent class with a `super` call?

Comment: @Glibdud, I have around a year of experience in Django, and I am still uncomfortable with advanced topics like `super`-calls. Could you please provide minimum code snippet illustrating what you found (I posted question after two hours of googling)

Comment: The first result of the above search led to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4634274/789671).